# How do I make my app automatically click on a button in react native?

Tags: react-native

I'm coding in react native and I want to create a way for my code to automatically click on a button once the app is opened by user. I want the button to be clicked by the app automatically without the user having to click on the button themselves. My code so far is:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View,Button } from 'react-native';
import {openBrowserAsync} from 'expo-web-browser'


export default function App() {
  const btnRef = useRef();

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        
      
      <Button title="Open Browser" onPress={() => openBrowserAsync("https://dicateeu.co.uk")}  />
      
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

My code so far just opens a web browser but I want the app to open the web browser by itself.

Comment: Why not just call openBrowserAsync function directly?

Comment: @user18309290 How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Use `useEffect` hook. It will execute on component mount.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';  
   
...
 
useEffect(() => {
  openBrowserAsync('https://dicateeu.co.uk');
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `useEffect` hook to trigger button's `onPress` function after the component has been mounted:

```
useEffect(() => {
  btnRef.current?.props.onPress()
}, [])
```